# Complicated MySql query using state IN ()

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a situation; in a table column/s named `foo` I have dynamically `implode()`d varchar data like `1,2,3,4` or `2,3` or `1,3` and so on.

Later, in code there is recognized string `$ce = 3;` before query of course, ready to draw resources from `foo` columns containing number 3.

Now I'm using following select..

```
SELECT DISTINCT place FROM xx WHERE she = 1
                      AND foo IN ($ce)
```

That doesnt do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT place FROM xx WHERE she = 1
                      AND $ce IN (foo)
```

doesnt do it also.

Where Im wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: >Any ideas? - normalizing data;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what the IN clause is intended for.

Instead, use the instr function, as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT place FROM xx WHERE she = 1 AND instr(foo, $ce) > 0
```

You can also use regular expressions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks Squawknull :)

Comment: Also, FIND_IN_SET function can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT place FROM xx WHERE she = 1 AND FIND_IN_SET('$ce',foo)
```

This should work for you.